# setOnTouchListener issue with a custom view

Tags: android, class, view

I have created a custom view - on the view class itself, I do some calculations during the OnTouch event - it appears as follows:

```
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          pointJoyPos.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
          UpdateJoy();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
          pointJoyPos.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
          UpdateJoy();
    }  else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          pointJoyPos.set(pointJoyCentre.x,pointJoyCentre.y);
          UpdateJoy();
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I add this view to my XML to display to the user,  I want to display the latest values, e.g. of pointJoyPos, so I wrote the following ...

```
THE_CUSTOM_VIEW.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ValX = THE_CUSTOM_VIEW.GetValOfX();
            return false;
        }
    }
    );
```

...Where GetValOfX is located in the custom view class as is meant to to return pointJoyPos.X.

The problem I have is that I am getting values one step delayed,  I think what is happening is that onTouchEvent of the custom view is running on the main activity before on the custom view itself.

I hope this is clear!

Any suggestions on how to overcome this such that the latest values are displayed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is having the same trouble, I just sorted this by creating a custom Event ...

https://gist.github.com/pipiscrew/10004381